# Socket.io io.use fails - TypeError: io.use is not a function

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a project that needs socket handshake session I'm trying to get this code to work, that I got it from https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

```
var app = require('express')(),
  server  = require("http").createServer(app),
  io = require("socket.io")(server),
  session = require("express-session")({
    secret: "my-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }),
  sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");


// Attach session
app.use(session);

// Share session with io sockets

io.use(sharedsession(session));

io.on("connection", function(socket) {

    // I've add this one...
    console.log(socket.handshake.session);

    // Accept a login event with user's data
    socket.on("login", function(userdata) {
        socket.handshake.session.userdata = userdata;
    });
    socket.on("logout", function(userdata) {
        if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
            delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
        }
    });        
});

server.listen(3000);
```

I run it and first I got this

```
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
                             ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Jack/Root/Sites/Scopone/provaric/server.js:8:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

solved adding

io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

and then I got this one

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    ^

TypeError: io.use is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Jack/Root/Sites/Scopone/provaric/server.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

Any ideas to fix this?

socket.io@0.9.17

Comment: Can you upgrade socket.io? 0.9.17 is extremely old now.

Comment: @slugonamission I've download the newest node.js v5.4.1 with npm v3.3.12.. I've uninstalled socket.io and I run npm install socket.io: when I check the socket version with npm list socket.io, I still get socket.io@0.9.17.. What do you suggest?

Comment: @slugonamission I've tried to install with npm install socket.io@1.4.3 and it goes trought but I got this

---
sudo npm install socket.io@1.4.3

chat@0.0.1 /Users/Jack/Root/Sites/Scopone/provaric
└─┬ socket.io@1.4.3  invalid
.....

npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON chat@0.0.1 license should be a valid SPDX license expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it upgrading nmp, node.js and socket.io. But to do that, I had to find out I had all my dependencies messed up: with those wrong I couldn't upgrade the packages..

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem in the same context. Even though your question is up here for a while,I will post my approach.

*The whole problem was that i used:*

```
var io = require('socket.io');
```

**But it should be:**

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
```

Everything else is working without those braces at the end but apparently io.use does not.

Instead of passing the Server I did:

```
app.io = io;
```

**In /bin/www**

```
  app.io.attach(server);
```

Hope that this is useful to someone.

UPDATE: I use Socket 1.5.2.

Comment: Experienced same problem in `"socket.io": "^3.0.3"`
Using `const io = require('socket.io')();` fixed it

Comment: I legitimately just ran into this error in 3.0.3 while having not had this error until 'npm update'

Comment: socket.io version 4.2.0 still requires this fix to import in nodejs